# How to add persistent headers in requests calls?

Tags: python, python-requests

It is possible to add a [custom header](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) to a `requests` call, but is there a way to make it *persistent*, i.e. to have the header added to every call without the need to specify it each time?

Comment: It would be helpful to know more of the context of which you're working in, like what libraries/frameworks are you using? Some frameworks have middleware that you can hook into, or you could wrap a library depending on the use case.

Comment: @digitaldreamer: there is no framework, I am writing a script around an API which requires an authorization header for each call (after having been authenticated).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object.

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. Sessions can also be used to provide default data to the request methods. This is done by providing data to the properties on a Session object:
>
> ```
> s = requests.Session()
> s.auth = ('user', 'pass')
> s.headers.update({'x-test': 'true'})
>
> # both 'x-test' and 'x-test2' are sent
> s.get('http://httpbin.org/headers', headers={'x-test2': 'true'})
> ```